# Hungarian Algorithm - PHP version

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to implement the job assignment Hungarian algorithm.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_terms_of_bipartite_graphs

[I think I understand the algorithm, but am not able to appreciate why is it O(n^3).  But that is just a curiosity.]

What I am looking for is a PHP implementation of Hungarian algorithm.  The Wikipedia link does have a link to implementations, but I have not found PHP version yet.

Comment: What about a Floyd-Warshall implementation? Does it help?

Comment: Not really.  But based on your suggestion, I realized that Ford Fulkerson might help - I will check if I can find PHP code for that. +1 for making me think outside of (Hungarian) box.

Comment: Topcoder has a great article about the algorithm if you want to implement it: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm Otherwise you could simply translate one of the wikipedia ones.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, if I do translate one of Wikipedia ones, I will definitely share it back. (But I will give it till weekend to find one.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to look at this article Floyd-Warshall and the all-pairs-shortest-path problem. Unfortunately it is in C but it can help you with the implementation in php ( http://wilanw.blogspot.com/2010/01/floyd-warshall-all-pairs-shortest-path.html ).

Answer (score 0):

This code in Python should be fairly easy to translate to PHP

http://pastebin.com/tn6v0HDr